# Function to flip the bit of the $nth$ binary digit

Tags: functions, binary, bit-strings

In programming, every number is expressed in binary-- for example, the number $5$ is $101$. In this concept, we can "flip the bit" of a specific digit. For example, flipping 5's first digit yields $100$ (first digit is the rightmost one, and the last digit is the leftmost one in this case).

Is there a mathematical function, $F_n(x)$, that inputs any number $x$ and outputs another number $y$ where $y$ is $x$ with the $nth$ bit flipped?

I found a solution for the case with a maximum of $2$ bits:

$F_1(x) = -x + 1 \: (mod \: 4)$ flips the first bit

$F_2(x) = x + 2 \: (mod \: 4)$ flips the second bit

However, this only works for the case of $2$ bits, as if we input $5$, we don't get $4$, but rather $0$.

Also, this function makes use of modulus, and is not continuous or differentiable. This function would only need to work with integers, and can output anything for fractional inputs.

Is there a "nice" function that does this?

Comment: A function that flips a bit cannot be continuous. $F_1(10.11111)=11.11111$, while $F_1(11)=(10)$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I'm not sure what you mean; the output of the fractional inputs (like 10.11111) wouldn't matter. It would only need to satisfy continuity. 

I'm not sure how bit flips work with floating point numbers, but I'm only really concerned with integer solutions. I'll edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: Isn't this a function $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$? So it is always continuous.

Comment: If you work only with integers, then the fact that the function is not continuous (when applied to real numbers) is not a problem, except from an aesthetic viewpoint. But I agree that aesthetics is valuable.

Comment: @MPW But this function would be able to input real numbers. The output of them just wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get something continuous or differentiable, because the bit-flipping operation inherently has jumps in it. Even if we define it for all real numbers (since the fractional part doesn't matter anyway), the flipping-the-$k^{\text{th}}$-bit function is going to be:

- $x + 2^{k-1}$ for $0 \le x < 2^{k-1}$ (since the bit is flipped from $0$ to $1$);
- $x - 2^{k-1}$ for $2^{k-1} \le x < 2^k$ (since the bit is flipped from $1$ to $0$);
- $x + 2^{k-1}$ for $2^k \le x < 3 \cdot 2^{k-1}$;
- and so on.

At every multiple of $2^{k-1}$, there will be a jump, breaking any semblance of continuity.

We can compute which multiple of $2^{k-1}$ we're at by $\lfloor \frac{x}{2^{k-1}}\rfloor$, where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes rounding down. Then the function can be expressed as
$$
    F_k(x) = x + (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{2^{k-1}}\right\rfloor} \cdot 2^{k-1}
$$
though, again, this will not be continuous.

I should note that this is useful for typing into a calculator (or in some scenarios, into a computer). But if you're communicating with humans, "flip the $k^{\text{th}}$ bit, where the rightmost bit is bit $1$" is a better description than the formula.

Answer (score 0):

How about $F_n(x)=x\oplus 2^{n-1}$ where $\oplus$ denotes binary addition without carry.